# Is there a way to list details of all objects in a SSIS package?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I have a whole bunch of Sequence Containers, each of which contains a whole bunch of objects such as Data Flow tasks, Execute SQL Tasks, etc.  I am trying to get some kind of inventory of everything in the whole SSIS package.  Is there a way to list all the details, specifically of Data Flows (i.e., OLE DB Data Source, OLE DB Data Destination, etc.).  I can use C#, VB.NET, SSIS...if this is even possible.  Or, perhaps some other tool, language, etc.  Thanks!!

Comment: The dtsx file is XML; you can parse it with `XDocument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PragmaticWorks sells a tool BIDocumenter that produces a help file describing the package.

BimlStudio can be used to reverse engineer a package and distill it down to the basic elements (as Biml). Biml is a far terser syntax than the core XML that defines the DTSX pacakge

BIDSHelper used to have functionality to identify non-default properties but nothing to the level I think you're looking for.

Otherwise, you're looking at custom code using the SSIS object model to instantiate the package and potentially project (ispac) depending on version and deployment model and then iterate through each task and container and tease out the attributes you are interested in. 
It gets uglier in the Data Flow as you're working with COM objects there. 
And then finally, you *get* to factor in things like Expressions. My Database Connection Manager may have a connection string pointing at DevServer at rest. However, there might be an expression defined that changes the connection string to ProdServer. And it might not be a direct relationship. There might be a Variable assigned to an Expression on the ConnectionString property. And that Variable might have an expression set based on the variables ServerName and DatabaseName. Etc, etc, etc.

I last tried this 2009ish. Maybe things are better/easier but I doubt it.

For me and my time/money, I'd reach for Biml as they've solved the hard parts. The evaluation copy of Biml Studio will get you ... I think 5 reverse engineerings and if you email them, they might send you a beta copy of the new version - the documentation features in there are pretty sweet.

Comment: Thanks billinkc!  I ended up changing the extension to XML, then double-clicked the file, and got everything I needed right there.  Just had to hunt and peck a bit for the specific names of objects that I needed.  There seems to be tons and tons and tons of other stuff going on in the background.  Maybe when I have time someday, I'll take a closer look at it.